# Microsoft Edge drop-down menu does not stay

Tags: windows-10, gui, microsoft-edge

In Microsoft Edge on Windows 10, when I tap on drop down menus, they won't remain for long. For example, in eBay when, I tap on my eBay drop down, it is shown only for few seconds and goes away very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem on a Windows 10 PC.
Executing sfc /scannow as dectibed in [System file check (SFC) Scan and Repair System Files](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-update/system-file-check-sfc-scan-and-repair-system-files/bc609315-da1f-4775-812c-695b60477a93) fixed it.
Cf [Microsoft Edge - dropdown menues cannot allow you to select](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-msedge/microsoft-edge-dropdown-menues-cannot-allow-you-to/b4ef8536-95f3-4c0b-b476-2bd3b3b8c97d?auth=1&rtAction=1439915181871)

Comment: Oops today I have again the initial problem

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the problem , 
its because the websites I tested are not fully compatible with windows tablet mode in windows 10 using Microsoft edge , so , eventually they are going to update themselves and this problem wont occur again , I tried with some other websites like Microsoft itself and intel and dropdowns was just fine ,